# Python Dbf append to memory indexed table fails

Tags: python-3.8, dbf

I'm using Python dbf-0.99.1 library from Ethan Furman. This approach to add record to table fails:

```
tab = dbf.Table( "MYTABLE" )
tab.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
idx = tab.create_index(lambda rec: (rec.id if not is_deleted(rec) else DoNotIndex ) ) # without this, append works
rec = { "id":id, "col2": val2 } # some values, id is numeric and is not None
tab.append( rec ) # fails here
```

My table contains various character and numeric columns. This is just an example. The exceptions is:

```
line 5959, in append
newrecord = Record(recnum=header.record_count, layout=meta, kamikaze=kamikaze)
line 3102, in __new__
record._update_disk()
line 3438, in _update_disk
index(self)
line 7550, in __call__
vindex = bisect_right(self._values, key)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: Here is testing script

```
import dbf
from dbf import is_deleted, DoNotIndex

tab = dbf.Table('temptable', "ID N(12,0)" )
tab.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
rc = { "id":1 }
tab.append( rc ) # need some data without index first
idx = tab.create_index(lambda rec: (rec.id if not is_deleted(rec) else DoNotIndex ) )
rc = { "id":2 }
tab.append( rc ) # fails here
```

Comment: Using your simplified data I am unable to duplicate the issue.  Can you send me a copy of the table and the actual index you are using?

Comment: I didn't expect this fast response. I added an example. Maybe this is not allowed way to work with indexes. When I think about it, I could create index in advance. Thanks anyway.

Comment: It should work.  I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks. I tested also option with index created before first append. Fails too.

Comment: Also, bit off topic. Would it be please possible to add Slovenian code page in future versions? In dbf/__init__.py its around line 8300, code_pages -> 0x87 : ('cp852', 'Slovenian OEM'). If not, no problem. Just asking.

Comment: Done.  It will be in the next release.  Thanks for letting me know it existed!

Comment: Thank you very much.